# match and rename values inside a .csv column to filenames present in a directory

Tags: powershell, csv, match, rename

Currently trying to see if there's a way of partially matching entries inside a specific .csv column to a list of specific files within a directory - then renaming the matched entries, so they exactly represent the files.

For example - if I have a series of files as follows:

```
23.54_0.DXF
24.58_0.1.DXF
25.01_0.DXF
```

and the entries in the .csv column are:

```
23.54 - Gusset
24.58 - shell plate
25.01 - reopad
```

I want to rename the .csv entries to instead be:

```
23.54_0.DXF
24.58_0.1.DXF
...
```

I've seen quite a few examples of the inverse scenario (renaming files based on .csv columns), but cannot seem to find an example that represents what I'm trying to achieve here.

The following has allowed me to get the .csv entries to "match" the file names when the rev number is constant (the "_X" that follows the partname), but it is not as flexible as it would be if I were to get it to work as described above:

```
$rev=gci -path "$FolderPath" -Filter *.DXF | Select-Object -first 1
$RevA=$rev.ToString().Substring(5) -replace(".DXF") -replace('[a-z]') -replace('-') -replace 
'\s',''
$BOM=gci -path "$FolderPath" -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -first 1
Import-Csv -Path "$FolderPath\$BOM" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.PartName = "$($_.PartName -replace('[a-z]') -replace('-') -replace '\s','')$RevA.DXF" 
    $_.Thickness = "$($_.Thickness)" -replace("PL") 
    $_ 
} | Export-Csv -Path "$FolderPath\PrimeCutImport$RevA.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[windows.forms.messagebox]::show('Updated')
```

Is there a way of listing all `.DXF`'s in a directory, grabbing all entries within a column (in this case column header is "PartName" `($_.PartName)`) and then matching the first 4-5 characters in each entry to the corresponding files that share the same first 4-5 characters in the filename?

For each match, I want the column entries to then be named according to the filename instead. No idea if this is going in the right direction:

```
$filedirectory="C:\Directory\etc\folder"
$tester=Import-csv $filedirectory\example.csv
$listdxf=gci $filedirectory -filter *.DXF
foreach($file in $listdxf){
foreach($item in $tester){
# Not sure how to do this to only match the first 4 characters - trying to use the substring returns an error.
if($item.name.tostring.substring(0,4) -eq 
$file.basename.tostring.substring(0,4)){
rename-item $item.name -newname 
"$($file.basename).$($file.extension)" -Verbose
}
}
}
```

The above is edited from code that takes a .csv file to then rename files - which is the opposite of what I want. Way too much of a novice to know how to go about this, any ideas and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with piping directly to `Export-Csv` after your `Foreach-Object` is that it gets overwritten each time with the new entry. You'd have to perform the operation first, then export.

Without accounting for other potential names that could be duplicate, you can split the `PartName` grabbing what's before the hyphen (`-`). Then you would be able to match by the first part of the name up to the underscore (`_`) on the file name itself.

```
$names = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter '*.DXF' -Name
(
    Import-Csv -Path "$filedirectory\example.csv" | % {
        $part = ($_.PartName -split ' -')[0]
        $file_match = $names.Name | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -match "^${part}_" }
        $_.PartName = if ($file_match) { $file_match } else { $_.PartName }
        $_
    }
) | Export-Csv -Path "$filedirectory\example.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

`$names`, as the name suggests, holds the file names ending with the extension of `*.DXF`. This is where the match happens as you're comparing the current iteration of `PartName` to the beginning of the file name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! I tried running this against a bunch of files in a directory and a dummy .csv, I changed the $part=($_.PartName -split ' - ')[0] to $part=($_.PartName.substring(0,4))[0] as the entries inside the .csv won't always include a "-". The partname will nearly always be XX.XX. Running this doesn't seem to result in the entries in the output .csv reflecting the file names - instead I just get the part number without underscore, rev# or file extension (i.e; 20.09 instead of 20.09_0.DXF). I think this is the if statement not passing - output .csv is the same as input .csv.